# Due ADC specs: full power bandwidth

Tags: arduino-due

I'm trying to compute Johnson resistance noise in a simple resistor circuit. However, since all frequencies contribute equally, I am getting an answer of infinity.

It then dawned upon me that the Arduino ADC probably detect frequencies larger than some cut off given by something called the full power bandwidth. Does anyone know this spec for the Due?

Comment: Does Arduino.cc not have the specs you need?